# I want to do a test to see if a button exists but it doesn't see the test

Tags: python, unit-testing, tkinter

i want to do a test to see if a button exists but it doesn't see the test.

Using the invoke () function I click on it and check if it exists

How fix it?

test.py

```
import tkinter as tkinter
import unittest
from tkinter import *

from main import command, command2


class MyGUI(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        var = IntVar()
        Radiobutton(self, text='Легкая', variable=var, value=0).pack()
        Radiobutton(self, text='Нормальная', variable=var, value=1).pack()
        Radiobutton(self, text='Сложная', variable=var, value=2).pack()
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Играть", command=lambda: command()).pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Выйти", command=lambda: command2()).pack()

class   TKinterTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.root:
            self.root.destroy()

    def test_enter1(self):
        v = MyGUI(self.root)
        v.button1.invoke()
        self.assertTrue(v.button1.winfo_ismapped())

    def test_enter2(self):
        v = MyGUI(self.root)
        v.button2.invoke()
        self.assertTrue(v.button2.winfo_ismapped())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Add code that other people can just copy from the question, run it and check what's wrong with it.

Comment: @8349697,add main.py?

Comment: You got error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoke'`?

Comment: @8349697 no,my error:Empty suite

Comment: Try to run this file separately, outside of your test suite and your IDE.

Comment: @EugeneSaitamovich The `NoneType` error *will* be a problem; `pack` doesn't return a reference to the button. You need two lines: `self.button1 = Button(...); self.button1.pack()`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with this code. If I comment out the `from main import ...` line (as you haven't provided a module named `main`), the tests run and fail with the error @8349697 points out.

Comment: This is not only a problem with the code, but also with the [detection of test files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery).